# How to check size of a directory given by user as an argument?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I want to get the size of a directory given by user as an argument.
Example:

```
read -p "Enter the directory" target

du -k $target
```

If user gives path as `~/Documents/dir`, I am getting error msg: `du: cannot access '~/Documents/dir': No such file or directory`

Whereas if i give the command as:

```
du -k ~/Documents/dir
```

I am getting the desired output.

Why am I not able to use variables along with du command?

Comment: Did try try running with script with `-x`? Also what is the folder the script is working on and does the user supply a full path or a relative path?

Comment: Tried with -x also, no help. Path given by the user is same as the path given along with du command as in the second case. The folder in which script is running is a different one.

Comment: The code does not perform _tilde expansion_.  The solution is not to use `~`.  Specify the the path, either relative or absolute, without using `~`.  For example, instead of `~/Documents/dir`, write `/home/myself/Documents/dir`.

Comment: Reading parameters line by line is so 1980... These days either you use parameters in the command line or you provide a UI. You are also preventing the user from using the shell's tab-completion to enter the file names. Using command line parameters is simpler!

Comment: Otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash/27485157#27485157

Comment: `read -e` gives tab-completion for file names in the input line (but won't handle the tilde...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` is not expanded after it is read in over the shell, nor when it is placed into the `du` command. You can force bash to do the expansion with the following code:

```
read -p "Enter the directory" target
target=${target/#\~/$HOME}
du -k "${target}"
```

The `${target/#\~/$HOME}` is the important part. It replaces `~` with the contents of the `HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Consider what happens if, as the directory name, the user enters `~root/dir`.